# How to clear all of the Activities from Stack in API 8?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an application in which I am following a hierarchy, there is an option from which user can Login, after this I am finishing the Login Activity. Now once user gets logged in I am taking him to a new Activity suppose "Activity A". From this activity again a new Activity is being starting called "Activity B" without finishing the "Activity A". And finally there is a last Activity named as "Activity C" which gets started from "Activity B" without finishing "Activity B". So currently all of the three activities are is stack.

Now, Every screen or Activity has an option called Logout, If the user is on "Activity A", I am just finishing the Activity and Opening Login Activity. For this scenario its working fine but Once I am switching to "Activity B" or Activity C" and then if user press Logout what should I do to remove all of the Activities in stack and also I have to open the Login Activity as I have finished it while successful login.

I know there is a FLAG in API 11 by using which we can clear all the activities in stack :-

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, LoginGateway.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);
```

But I am supporting it from API 8. I want a solution which I can use for API 8 onward, please help me to find out that. 
Any help would be appreciable. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginGateway.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
activity.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it ?

Comment: it's beautiful, comrade) so you can restart your acticity task simply in any point.

Answer (score 0):

try this variant

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, LoginGateway.class);
    i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I have done that but even if I am logging out from second activity after login, and then pressing back button its taking me to first activity that means its in stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it works fine with me**

```
// clear whole activity stack

    Intent intent = new Intent("clearStackActivity");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

// start your new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(OrderComplete.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Step : 1**

Put these line in onCreate() method of all Activities or if you have any base activity you can put it there , then no need to put in all activities.

```
private KillReceiver clearActivityStack;
clearActivityStack = new KillReceiver();
        registerReceiver(clearActivityStack, IntentFilter.create("clearStackActivity", "text/plain"));
```

**Step : 2**

Put this class in your Base activity

```
private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**Explanation :**

In above code we created our custom broadcast receiver. And we are registering it in base activity i.e in all activity which invokes.

When we wants to finish all activities we just broadcast intent, so all activity which are register this receiver will notify and finish them self.

Comment: can you just explain it a bit so I can apply it, it would be helpful, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi I added the explanation with answer just look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.  It's been available since API 1.